# Pycharm not able to detect django channels

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-channels

I am using pycharm for django and it is not able to detect channels when i am importing it

[image]

My settings files is as follow:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'dating',
    'notif_sender',
    'rest_framework'
]
```

Is there any way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Pycharm Community or Professional edition? Django is supported only in the Professional one:
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: I am using community edition. Is there any plugin to get it done? Also, why isn't this happening with other packages?

Comment: Never done that, but there were some who tried: https://automationpanda.com/2017/09/14/django-projects-in-pycharm-community-edition/ There are many libraries supported by Community edition, but some are reserved for Professional. Otherwise who would pay for it? :)